# Different displaying of input inside span in Chrome and FF

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have input inside span and some HTML-code.

```
<div class="SCnField">
<div class="SCnFieldMarker">
    ⇒
</div>
<div class="SCnFieldValue">
    <span class="scAttribute selectedSCnNode">
        <span class="twitter-typeahead" style="position: relative; display: inline-block;">
            <input type="text" data-name="true" class="typeahead scn-input tt-hint"
                   disabled="" autocomplete="off"
                   spellcheck="false"
                   style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; border-color: transparent; box-shadow: none;">
            <input type="text" data-name="true" class="typeahead scn-input tt-input" autocomplete="off"
                   spellcheck="true" dir="auto"
                   style="position: relative; vertical-align: top; background-color: transparent;">
            <pre aria-hidden="true" style="position: absolute; visibility: hidden; white-space: nowrap;"></pre>
            <span class="tt-dropdown-menu"
                  style="position: absolute; top: 100%; left: 0px; z-index: 100; display: none;">
            <div class="tt-dataset-idtf">

            </div>
        </span>
        </span>
        <div class="atrribute-colon">:</div>
    </span>
</div>
```

Fiddle with styles: https://jsfiddle.net/bq7Lsw2L/

Difference in FF and Chrome display:

[image: FF vs. Chrome]

I experimened with vertical-align, display, margins, paddings and so on... But there are no results
How can I fix vertical align in FF?
Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you need a reset and also you need to use `vertical-align: middle`.

Comment: thanks, add vertical-align to '.twitter-typeahead' resolved my problem

Comment: Okay I will add that as an answer then. So that you can accept.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You can't place `pre` nor `div` elements inside `span`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As per the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36828640/different-displaying-of-input-inside-span-in-chrome-and-ff/36828692#comment61228477_36828640), I am adding this as an answer. You have this code in the CSS, that needs `vertical-align: middle`:

```css
.twitter-typeahead {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why Chrome centers it vertically automatically, but you should use

```css
.twitter-typeahead {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```css
.SCnField {
  min-height: 40px;
}
.SCnFieldMarker {
  width: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-top: 7px;
  margin-left: -32px;
}
.SCnFieldValue {
  display: inline-block;
}
.selectedSCnNode {
  border-left: 2px solid rgb(96, 230, 119) !important;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
.scn-input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 34px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: white;
}
.twitter-typeahead {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="SCnField"><div class="SCnFieldMarker">⇒</div><div class="SCnFieldValue"><span class="scAttribute selectedSCnNode"><span class="twitter-typeahead" style="position: relative; display: inline-block;"><input type="text" data-name="true" class="typeahead scn-input tt-hint" disabled="" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; border-color: transparent; box-shadow: none;"><input type="text" data-name="true" class="typeahead scn-input tt-input" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="true" dir="auto" style="position: relative; vertical-align: top; background-color: transparent;"><pre aria-hidden="true" style="position: absolute; visibility: hidden; white-space: nowrap;"></pre><span class="tt-dropdown-menu" style="position: absolute; top: 100%; left: 0px; z-index: 100; display: none;"><div class="tt-dataset-idtf"></div></span></span><div class="atrribute-colon">:</div></span></div></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I have something good to fix it
with the below code you can write specific style for FF

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
// css code for FF
}
```